# Como puedo darle estilos css a este formulario

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Como puedo darle estilos css a este formulario ? existe una mejor manera de crear formularios en codeigniter 3 ?

```
<h1>Formulario con Codeigniter 3</h1>

<?php 

echo validation_errors("<p style='background: red; color: #fff'>", "</p>") ?>

<?php echo form_open(base_url("home/save")) ?>

    <p><?php echo form_label("Username", "username") ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_input($username) ?></p>

    <p><?php echo form_label("Email", "email") ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_input($email) ?></p>

    <p><?php echo form_label("Password", "password") ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_input($password) ?></p>

    <p><?php echo form_label("Sexo", "sexo") ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_dropdown("sexo", $sexo) ?></p>

    <p><?php echo form_submit("submit", "Enviar") ?></p>

<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que cambias estilo a estos dos elementos:

```
<p><?php echo form_label("Username", "username") ?></p>
<p><?php echo form_input($username) ?></p>
```

Creas un array con propiedades que le vas a configurar a tus elementos HTML:

```
<?php 
    $attributes = array(
      'class' => 'label-stilo',
      'style' => 'color: #000;');
    $attributes2 = array(
      'class' => 'campo-stilo',
      'style' => 'color: #4c0;');
?>
    <p><?php echo form_label("Username", "username", $attributes) ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_input($username ,"", $attributes2 ) ?></p>
```

Arriba puedes cambiarlo por la clase css que uses ademas puedes definir varios arrays para atributos, puedes configurar otras propiedades html como para asignar eventos (Por ejemplo):

```
$atributos= array( "onclick"=> "metodoJsCualquiera()");
```